# AngularJS : ng-model directive

Tags: angularjs

Consider the code given below :

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index" >
    <input ng-model="task.completeStatus" ng-click="updateOnClick()"
           type="checkbox" 
           style="margin-right: 20px;" />
    <span class="{{task.completeStatus}}" ng-dblclick="editTaskMessage()" 
          contenteditable="false" ng-model="task.taskMessage"
          ng-keydown="enterEdit()">
      {{task.taskMessage}}
    </span>
</li>
```

My problem is, how can I access the `ng-model="task.completeStatus"` in the controller...? ( I tried to access the value returned from the `ng-model` in the controller as `$scope.task.completeStatus` but gives an error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'completeStatus' of undefined` ) and can the     `ng-model` directive be used to overwrite or modify currently existing values in the tasks array inside the controller.??

Comment: `ng-click="updateOnClick(task)"`

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<span>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your first question, you are getting the error because you are trying to access the property of array inside array without its index.

You can access the "task.completeStatus" in the controller by passing the $index of the array in tasks as below

`ng-click="updateOnClick($index)"`

And in the controller, you can access the "task.completeStatus" as below

```
function updateOnClick(index){
   var completeStatus = $scope.task[index].completeStatus);
}
```

2. Yes, you can modify the values present in task array in the controller, as ng-model provides two way binding of variables which means that you can change the value of the angular variable from the controller as well as from HTML.

Comment: Or you can pass `task` itself instead of `$index` and get `task.completeStatus`